# Is it possible to see deleted answers or at least who contributed a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers, serial-voting

I downvoted a completely wrong answer with a comment and in return the guy gave me a lot of downvotes. I want to identify the guy and hand him over to the moderators. Unfortunately, he has deleted his answer. I know that SO runs some kind of script to undo such serial downvotes, but I'd also like to make the guy realize repay for his acts in a reasonable way.
Is there a hall of shame for this ?

If you can help, here is the question where it all started - [Is it possible to retrieve Selected Columns from Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112797/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-selected-columns-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: LOL - the irony of it all. Care to tell me why you downvoted ?

Comment: Yes, everything starts with a goat sacrifice. Ping me when you have the animal for further instructions.

Comment: *I want to identify the guy and hand him over to the moderators. [...] I'd also like to make the guy realize repay for his acts in a reasonable way.* Hmm, would you like a side of Batmobile with that, Mr. Vigilante?

Comment: as for your feature request, you can see deleted post after 10K rep [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: I should point out that a string of votes like that should be automatically invalidated by the system at some point today, so we might not even need to intervene. Also, we can see deleted posts, and we can examine patterns of votes, so you wouldn't have needed to see that deleted post to flag us to look into this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry, we don't do blood feuds here, where a user throws a tantrum, then you set the authorities on them, then they swear to take your car, then you burn down the house, and for the next untold generations you assassinate each others families.

The user had a tantrum, their flailing will go undone, you *move on*.

In any case, you cannot even be certain that it was that specific user that serially downvoted your posts. Perhaps someone else got a brainstorm and hates all things Borat. Even the moderators cannot verify this, and they certainly won't publicly shame anyone. So, no, you cannot go out and play vigilante here. At best, you get to feel superior in the knowledge that they lost their cool and it was all over some stupid internet points and it didn't even *work*.

<sup>I hope you do take all this in and learn to love how we don't immediately go out and punish everyone for a stupid mistake like that. Because when you reach 10k reputation you earn [the right to see deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Not that it'll get you anything in this case, but we do hope that by that time you'd take this a little calmer.</sup>

Comment: LOL ! Good answer. I did not want revenge, but i wanted redressal which would also discourage serial downvoters. Anyway, it all worked out in the end, but at a cost of -17. Thank you very much my friend Martijn Pieters, I love you :)